# Fetch all links from a webpage

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get all the links from this [website](https://recetasgratis.net)

My code is:

```
import bs4
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

url_meva = https://www.recetasgratis.net'

uClient = uReq(url_meva)
pag_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

pag_soup = soup(pag_html, "html.parser")

containers = pag_soup.findAll("a",{"class":"titulo titulo--bloque"})
```

If I type len(containers) the result is 43, and it must be 25000 approximately.

Why I only get those 43 and not the rest?

The idea is to get the links of the recipes.
I know the website has the same structure for the recipes.

Thanks

Comment: You are grabbing all the title links for the home page. It sounds like you are trying to scrape all the data from the site, is that correct?

Comment: Yes. But I want to grab data of the links. I mean, I want to get all links, open them and get all data.

Answer (score 0):

What you are getting when you read the content of the url `https://www.recetasgratis.net` is the raw text from the link `view-source:https://www.recetasgratis.net/` which has exactly 43 instances of the class `titulo titulo--bloque`. You'll need to figure out the functions behind dynamic loading of the webpage and use it to your advantage to fetch the list of all links. Good luck with that.

Answer (score 0):

Your current implementation only scrapes the current home page.

To begin, if you want to start by grabbing all 25k recipe links, you are going to have to run this action for every page of their catalog starting from https://www.recetasgratis.net/busqueda/pag/1 to 574.

You can do this by building the url using a for loop and going thru each page, running

`pag_soup.findAll("a",{"class":"titulo titulo--bloque"})` for each page.

At that point you should have all the links and will be able to begin actually grabbing the data from each page- the implementation for which will be all your own.

I suggest using some sort of flat file data store to keep track of urls collected. Storing everything in memory is not recommended as one exception will break your entire 500+ page flow and make you need to start over.

Also, if this is not your website, please consider the [legal implications](https://www.import.io/post/6-misunderstandings-about-web-scraping/) of what you are doing.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I tried another way to do it using Selenium and BeautifulSoup. But I can't fetch all links. I'll ask another question.